# Texture2D ignored by GC

Tags: monogame

I loaded my textures with FromStream method and I noticed a problem that those textures are being ignored by garbage collector. I even nulled them, called dispose on them and tried to force garbage collector - they're still in the memory. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: did you try something like ContentManager.Unload() ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264995/how-do-i-unload-content-from-the-content-manager forcing garbage collection is really bad for performance

Comment: I am not using ContentManager. As I mentioned in my question, I use Texture2D.FromStream method to load it directly into memory.

Comment: Never mind. I found a solution.

Comment: Could you write your solution please ? To help the people who will face the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to call Dispose() on texture loaded with FromStream().